# How to do a partial match filter on an array from all elements of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, filtering

I'm trying to filter an array with partial matches from the entirety of another array. For example, the arrays are outlined below:

```
Array1 = 
     categories: 292300, 
     categories: 300, 
     categories: 292500280

Array2 = 
     300,
     498
```

With the filter, I would expect to return:

```
NewArray = 
     categories: 292300, 
     categories: 300
```

What is the best way to implement this? I've tried the code below with no luck:

```
  const NewArray = Array1.filter(Array1 => !(Array1.categories.includes(Array2)))
```

Comment: What do you mean by ```js Array1 = 
     categories: 292300, 
     categories: 300, 
     categories: 292500280```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do partal matching just need parse `int` to `string`

```js
const arr1 = [{categories: 292300}, {categories: 300}, {categories: 292500280}];
const arr2 = [300, 498];

const result = arr1.filter(({ categories }) => 
  arr2.some((e) => String(categories).includes(String(e))));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: This worked perfect for me! Thank you so much. It was the int to String that did it.

Answer (score 0):

Why new array also includes 292300 while it's not included in array2?

But if you want to filter array1 with data included in array2, there is the solution

```js
const NewArray = Array1.filter(({ categories }) => Array2.includes(categories))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const Array1 = [{ categories: 292300 }, { categories: 300 }, { categories: 292500280 }];

  const Array2 = [300, 498];
  const newArray = [];

  Array2.forEach((el) => {
    Array1.forEach((element) => {
      if (element.categories.toString().includes(el.toString())) {
        newArray.push(element);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).