# Google Apps Script to obtain the index if any of the words on a string match another string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, string-matching, indexof

I have a long list of roles obtained from a sheet range stored as strings in an array, to give an example the array looks something like this:

```
arr1 = ["football manager","hockey coach", "fb player","fb coach","footballer"];
```

and I have another array in which I have a small list of tags

```
arr2 = ["football","fb", "footballer","hockey","rugby"];
```

I am trying to match the roles of the first array to the tags on the second one.

I have been trying to do this by looping through and obtaining the index of the matched row:

```
for(let i in arr1){
arr2.findIndex(s => s.indexOf(arr1[i]) >= 0);
}
```

But this only works for "footballer" as it is an exact match, I need for all of the partial matches to be classified as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a partial match filter on an array from all elements of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70752669/how-to-do-a-partial-match-filter-on-an-array-from-all-elements-of-another-array)

Comment: @Kos It looks to be doing something similar, however this solution returns a value and I need to get an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following function to find indexes of tags (from `arr2` array) that match values from `arr1`.

Follow code comments for detailed explanation.

```
function matchTagIndexes()
{
  // TODO replace with your values
  arr1 = ["football manager","hockey coach", "fb player","fb coach","footballer"];

  // TODO replace with your tags
  arr2 = ["football","fb", "footballer","hockey","rugby"];

  // for all tags create regex objects
  // regex searches for any match that have `tag` surrounded with word (\b) boundaries 
  // see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet#boundary-type_assertions
  const arr2Regexes = arr2.map(tag => new RegExp(`\\b${tag}\\b`, 'i'));

  // loop arr1 values as val
  arr1.map(val => 
    // for each arr2 regex match val
    arr2Regexes.forEach((regex, i) => 
      // if it is matched, log value from arr1 array, matched tag name and tag's index in arr2 array
      val.match(regex) && console.log(`"${val}" matches tag "${arr2[i]}" which has index ${i}`)
    )
  );
}
```

Result:

| time | status | message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8:46:35 PM | Notice | Execution started |
| 8:46:35 PM | Info | "football manager" matches tag "football" which has index 0 |
| 8:46:35 PM | Info | "hockey coach" matches tag "hockey" which has index 3 |
| 8:46:35 PM | Info | "fb player" matches tag "fb" which has index 1 |
| 8:46:35 PM | Info | "fb coach" matches tag "fb" which has index 1 |
| 8:46:35 PM | Info | "footballer" matches tag "footballer" which has index 2 |
| 8:46:36 PM | Notice | Execution completed |

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet#boundary-type_assertions

Comment: thank you very much @Kos, this answer works to perfection and it is explained to the detail. awesome !

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there could be several tags for some of the texts (`arr1`). Here is the solution to get the array of tags (indexes) for every of the texts:

```js
var texts = ['football manager','hockey coach', 'fb player','fb coach','footballer', 'none'];
var tags = ['football','fb', 'footballer','hockey','rugby', 'coach'];

// get all tags for all the texts
var list = [];
for (let tag of tags) {
    var mask = RegExp('\\b' + tag + '\\b', 'i');
    for (let text of texts) {
        if (text.match(mask))
            list.push( {'text': text, 'tag': tag, 'tag_index': tags.indexOf(tag)} );
    }
}
console.log(list);

// group tags for the same texts
var text_and_tags = {};
for (let element of list) {
    try { text_and_tags[element.text].push(element.tag_index) }
    catch(e) { text_and_tags[element.text] = [element.tag_index] }
}
console.log(text_and_tags);
```

It will get you the object `text_and_tags` as follows:

```
{
  'football manager': [ 0 ],
  'fb player': [ 1 ],
  'fb coach': [ 1, 5 ],
  'footballer': [ 2 ],
  'hockey coach': [ 3, 5 ]
}
```